# Mount -t cifs works on one version of linux but not another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, mount, cifs

I have a raspberry pi that I am trying to mount a remote samba share on, but I get permission denied. On another mounting the same share with th same command works.

Raspberry pi:

```
root@xbian:~# mount -t cifs //192.168.249.72/root /media/SS -o username=root,password=654321
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
root@xbian:~# uname -a
Linux xbian 3.9.8+ #2 PREEMPT Tue Jul 2 17:38:12 CEST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Ubuntu:

```
root@dakLinux:~#  mount -t cifs //192.168.249.72/root /media/SS -o username=root,password=654321
root@dakLinux:~# uname -a
Linux dakLinux 2.6.31-17-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 10 16:20:31 UTC 2009 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Is this a kernel issue or a linux version issue? Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Try checking the permissions of the /media and the /media/SS directories?

Answer (score 9):

use `sec=ntlm` in the options

Kernel versions `post 3.8.x` have this changed, and `mount.cifs` doesn't pass this argument, explicitly, Hence fails

Refer: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=81bcd8b795229c70d7244898efe282846e3b14ce

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.249.72/root /media/SS -o username=root,password=654321,sec=ntlm
```

and it should work

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you saved my bacon Sundeep Borra. On Xubuntu 12.04, no problems. Xubuntu 14.04 my same scripts wouldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, 12.04 gets upgraded and upgraded but will never reach 3.8.x kernel, and in 14.04, your kernel version will be >= 3.8.x, hence you will find the issue, but using sec=ntlm will work with both 12.04 and 14.04.

Comment: This same situation can be reproduced for 4.10.X kernels. Thank you very much.