# mount error(95) cifs-utils on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, samba, network-drive, cifs

I can see a lot of these threads, but so far nothing has worked and it seems to be something cryptic that I'm at a loss to figure out.

I have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412617/mount-t-cifs-works-on-one-version-of-linux-but-not-another) roughly. I have 2 servers, both Ubuntu, but 1 on 12.04 and the other on 14.04.

I'm mapping an SMB shared drive from my university's infrastructure, but it works on 14.04, and not on 12.04.

I have the highest version of `cifs-utils` installed on each that I can (`2:6.0-1ubuntu2` on 14.04, and `2:5.1-1ubuntu1` on 12.04).

On 12.04, for the command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs "//foo.bar.warwick.ac.uk/HCSS1/Shared291/" ~/petabyte/ -o username=username,password=******,domain=ADS
```

I get the error:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

All the suggestions I can find so far suggest that the `sec` or `ver` should resolve any conflicts that seem to arise from old/unsupported SMB protocols - and this is what the sys admins at Uni think is the problem too, since they've said the servers are set up to reject SMB1.

However, I've tried the command with `sec=ntlm` and `ver=3.0`, and it makes no difference. Meanwhile on the 14.04 server, `ver=3.0` works fine.

The mismatched server versions/cifs versions might be a total red herring, but I am running out of other ideas as to what the problem could be.

Comment: did you try `smbmount` or `smbclient`?

Comment: `smbmount` seems to be fairly adamant it should no longer be used, in favour of `mount.cifs` or `mount -t cifs`, but in any event, it also refused to connect, but this time complained about no `/etc/fstab` entry. This confused me though, do these tools require that an entry be added to `fstab` *before* they can be mounted (at least once on an ad hoc basis)? I hadn't seen anything to suggest so in some of the `smbmount` guides I was following.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment so it maybe as well an answer:

The `smbmount` is a utility that mounts smbfs (internally calls `smbmnt`).  It should not need any record in `/etc/fstab`.  The utility actually calls `mount.smbfs` (`-t smbfs`).  You are right about that it has been  superseded by `mount.cifs`, but I wanted you to test it if that would work for you.  My guess is that you are actually having issues with the newer SMB protocol (as you have probably guessed).  Could you check if your package on Unt 12.04 supports (NTLM auth & the newer version of SMB protocol?).

My guess now is that you maybe have an old kernel with 12.04.  Which kernel version do you use?

If they reject SMB1, it could be they allow SMB2.  Could you try the following?:

```
sudo mount -t cifs "//foo.bar.warwick.ac.uk/HCSS1/Shared291/" ~/petabyte/ -o username=username,password=******,domain=ADS,vers=2.0
```

(`vers` not `ver`)

Comment: I've tried every combo of `vers` (and `sec`) I can think of (and my command history shows I was using `vers` not `ver`, so I must have mistyped this in my OP - apologies. Using `smbmount` is also throwing me the same error message as in the OP. It seems my cryptic `fstab` error must have been because I forgot to use `sudo` with the command. Using it now just gives error above.

Comment: @JoeHealey Ok.  Then do the following extract running kernel configuration (the `.config`) and compare both Ubuntu and see what is missing in your older kernel version.  My guess is that you are missing something that is required (like NTLM or some part of SMB2/3).  To get running kernel configuraiton check - https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system

Comment: This helped in my case since Ubuntu was trying to mount the SMB filesystem using default version 1. New releases of dd-wrt want me to use version 2.0 on Ubuntu and adding the `vers=2.0` string to /etc/fstab solved it.

Comment: @proteus I'm glad it helped.  Yes, forcing it is usually the only way to make it working.